# laravel same function for send two mail to two user with different view page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

> ```
> In laravel cron i have a function like  given below :
> ```

```
public function booking_mail()
{
  $data_to_mail= DB::table('tbl_booking as book')
                ->select('book.id as book_id','book.*','twd.id as wk_id','twd.*')
                ->join('tbl_workers_details as twd', 'twd.id', '=', 'book.worker_id')
                ->where('book.status','=','0')
                ->get();

            $data['viewpage']='mailtemplates.booking';
            $data['toemail']=$agent[0]->email;
            $data['listing_no']=$data_to_mail[0]->listing_no;
            $data['cv_no']=$data_to_mail[0]->cv_no;


            $mail= Mail::send($data['viewpage'], ['userdata'=>$data], function ($message) 
                use ($data) {
                        $message->to($data['toemail'],'Booking Mail')->subject('Inquiry Mail For Booking');
                if($data['attach']!=''){ 

                    $message->attach($data['attach']);
                }           
            });

            if($data['attach']!=''){ 
                unlink($data_to_mail[0]->civil_id_copy);
            }
            $result=DB::table('tbl_booking')
          ->where('id','=',$data_to_mail[0]->book_id)
          ->update(array(
          'status'=>'1',
          ));

}
```

> This function is working fine but when i added one for mail function
>   at the end of the function its not working returning me the error. i
>   dont know why this happening to me. i want to do this because i want
>   to send the mail for two different user with two different data and
>   view code is given below which is returning me the error.

```
public function booking_mail()
{
  $data_to_mail= DB::table('tbl_booking as book')
                ->select('book.id as book_id','book.*','twd.id as wk_id','twd.*')
                ->join('tbl_workers_details as twd', 'twd.id', '=', 'book.worker_id')
                ->where('book.status','=','0')
                ->get();

  $data['user_viewpage']='mailtemplates.enduser_booking';
                    $data['toemail']=$agent[0]->email;
                    $data['listing_no']=$data_to_mail[0]->listing_no;
                    $data['cv_no']=$data_to_mail[0]->cv_no;

    //send e-mail to the agent for booking
                    $mail= Mail::send($data['viewpage'], ['userdata'=>$data], function ($message) 
                        use ($data) {
                                $message->to($data['toemail'],'Booking Mail')->subject('Inquiry Mail For Booking');
                        if($data['attach']!=''){ 

                            $message->attach($data['attach']);
                        }           
                    });

                    $mail= Mail::send($data['user_viewpage'], ['userdata'=>$data], function ($message) 
                        use ($data) {
                                $message->to($data['toemail'],'Booking Mail')->subject('Confirmation mail');       
                    });

                    $result=DB::table('tbl_booking')
                  ->where('id','=',$data_to_mail[0]->book_id)
                  ->update(array(
                  'status'=>'1',
                  ));

}
```

why this is happening its returning me the error like:

Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268: Connection could not be established with host mail.XXXX.com [Connection timed out #110]

Comment: Look like your error is in connection establishment. which driver you using?

Comment: using smtp.. but its working fine with single mail function

Comment: @ Emtiaz Zahid ?? is there any solution ???

Comment: did you tried to send emails with event listener

Comment: No  i am simply doing this only for one mail function its working fine but for another it not working

Comment: Please have a look into this article : https://medium.com/@janaksan_/laravel-5-4-send-email-b78cca4c4569 . try to make two event to send email like ViewPageMail and UserViewPageMail and then call those events Mail::to($user1)->send(new ViewPageMail($data1));                  
Mail::to($user2)->send(new UserViewPageMail ($data2));

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined `$data["user_viewpage"]`.